# Why the XML file input of JAXB's xjc is different than mine?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

I'm trying to use JAXB's xjc to create Java classes from XML but in all of the examples I follow I see the XML is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="employee" type="employee"/>

  <xs:complexType name="employee">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="salary" type="xs:double"/>
      <xs:element name="designation" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="address" type="address" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="address">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="line1" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="line2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="state" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="zipcode" type="xs:long"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and mine is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE BlastOutput PUBLIC "-//NCBI//NCBI BlastOutput/EN" "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/dtd/NCBI_BlastOutput.dtd">
<BlastOutput>
  <BlastOutput_program>blastp</BlastOutput_program>
  <BlastOutput_version>BLASTP 2.2.28+</BlastOutput_version>
  <BlastOutput_reference>Stephen F. Altschul, Thomas L. Madden, Alejandro A. Sch&amp;auml;ffer, Jinghui Zhang, Zheng Zhang, Webb Miller, and David J. Lipman (1997), &quot;Gapped BLAST and PSI-BLAST: a new generation of protein database search programs&quot;, Nucleic Acids Res. 25:3389-3402.</BlastOutput_reference>
  <BlastOutput_db>nr</BlastOutput_db>
  <BlastOutput_query-ID>59663</BlastOutput_query-ID>
  <BlastOutput_query-def>unnamed protein product</BlastOutput_query-def>
  <BlastOutput_query-len>59</BlastOutput_query-len>
  <BlastOutput_param>
    <Parameters>
      <Parameters_matrix>BLOSUM62</Parameters_matrix>
      <Parameters_expect>10</Parameters_expect>
      <Parameters_gap-open>11</Parameters_gap-open>
      <Parameters_gap-extend>1</Parameters_gap-extend>
      <Parameters_filter>F</Parameters_filter>
    </Parameters>
  </BlastOutput_param>
<BlastOutput_iterations>
<Iteration>
  <Iteration_iter-num>1</Iteration_iter-num>
  <Iteration_query-ID>59663</Iteration_query-ID>
  <Iteration_query-def>unnamed protein product</Iteration_query-def>
  <Iteration_query-len>59</Iteration_query-len>
<Iteration_hits>
<Hit>
  <Hit_num>1</Hit_num>
  <Hit_id>gi|28592|emb|CAA23754.1|</Hit_id>
  <Hit_def>serum albumin [Homo sapiens]</Hit_def>
  <Hit_accession>CAA23754</Hit_accession>
  <Hit_len>609</Hit_len>
  <Hit_hsps>
    <Hsp>
      <Hsp_num>1</Hsp_num>
      <Hsp_bit-score>126.716</Hsp_bit-score>
      <Hsp_score>317</Hsp_score>
      <Hsp_evalue>2.38539e-38</Hsp_evalue>
      <Hsp_query-from>1</Hsp_query-from>
      <Hsp_query-to>59</Hsp_query-to>
      <Hsp_hit-from>1</Hsp_hit-from>
```

and so on ...

What should I do? 
I'm originally trying to use this to parse balst xml file and for that I need this.

Answer (score 3):

XJC is used to create JAVA classes from XSD file (XML Schema) not from XML. If you wants to populate the object of your java class generated using XJC then you can consider using JAXB.

JAXB is an XML-to-Java binding technology that enables transformation between schema and Java objects and between XML instance documents and Java object instances. JAXB technology consists of a runtime API and accompanying tools that simplify access to XML documents. You can use JAXB APIs and tools to establish mappings between Java classes and XML schema. An XML schema defines the data elements and structure of an XML document. JAXB technology provides a runtime environment to enable you to convert your XML documents to and from Java objects. Data stored in an XML document is accessible without the need to understand the XML data structure.

Answer (score 1):

The XJC is used to generate Java classes with [jaxb](/questions/tagged/jaxb) ([JSR-222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)) annotations from an XML Schema ([xsd](/questions/tagged/xsd)).  XML Schema is a standard way of defining the structure of an [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) document (see: http://www.w3.org/XML/Schema).  Once you have the generated classes you can use them with a JAXB implementaion to parse/create documents that conform to that XML Schema.

The XML in your question conforms to a Document Type Definition ([dtd](/questions/tagged/dtd)).  A DTD file is another way of defining the structure of an XML document.  You can run the XJC tool with the `-dtd` option to produce JAXB classes from a DTD.

```
xjc -d out -p com.example.blastoutput  -dtd http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/dtd/NCBI_BlastOutput.dtd
```

Below is a sample of JAXB code that shows how to convert your XML document to instances of the generated classes and then back to XML.  Note how we create the `JAXBContext` on the package name we specified in the XJC call.

```
package com.example.blastoutput;

import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.blastoutput");

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/com/example/blastoutput/input.xml");
        BlastOutput blastOutput = (BlastOutput) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(blastOutput, System.out);
    }

}
```